# How to access method in abstract class

Tags: java

I have an abstract class NoiseMaker with an abstract method makeNoise that I want to access from Test class. I need to put som code in the doSomething method.  I just can't figure out what to write in it. I want the output to be 
"Scream out load: ROAR"

```
public interface MakeNoiser{
    public void doSomething();
}



public class Test implements MakeNoiser {
    public Test() {}

    public void setNoiseMaker(NoiceMaker nm) {
       nm.makeNoise();
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        //What to write in this method to print out "ROAR"?
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setNoiseMaker(new Scream("ROAR"));
        t.doSomething();
    }    
}



public abstract class NoiseMaker {
    private String noiseName;

    public NoiseMaker(String noiseName) {
        this.noiseName= noiseName;
    }

    public abstract void makeNoise();

    public String getNoiseName() {
        return noiseName;
    }    
}



public class Scream extends NoiseMaker {    
    public Scream(String noiseName) {
        super(noiseName);
    }

    @Override
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Scream out load: ");
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is `Test.doSomething` supposed to `@Override`?  `Test` only inherits from `java.lang.Object` which does not have a `doSomething` method.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the interface that the Test-class inherits. I have the method doSomething in that interface.

Comment: Neither Test Class or NoiseMaker are implementing any interfaces in your posted code.

Comment: I have updated it now.

Answer (score 2):

You're literally right there.  You just forgot to print out the sound in your overridden method.

```
@Override
public void makeNoise() {
    System.out.println("Scream out load: " + getNoiseName());
}
```

`doSomething` doesn't have anything to do with `NoiseMaker`, so I'm not sure why you would require that function at all if all you wanted to do was print out some noise.

I'll leave the typo as a genuine issue you need to solve (`NoiceMaker` instead of `NoiseMaker`), but the rest of the code should work after you add that `getNoiseName()` call.

Comment: Actually making Test a subclass of NoiseMaker would also be needed

Comment: Not necessarily.  It makes more sense for it to be a driver class than another thing that extends.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to use the method doSomething. I have instructions of the methods I need to use )

Comment: In that case, you have to determine why it's needed.  I would encourage you to talk to your professor or instructor; figure out why they decreed that you use this method in the first place.  To a professional, I see it as unneeded and confusing.

Comment: Confusing, yes I agree with you. That´s why I can´t figure it out and need your help. I have an UML I need to follow.

Comment: You let me know when you've determined the purpose of that function and I'll help you out.  Right now, I answered the question on its own merits, but I'll need more info to really be of any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to use abstract classes in java.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sounds s = new Sounds() {

            @Override
            public void lol() {
                System.out.print("hi");
            }

        };
        s.lol();
    }

}

abstract class Sounds {
    public abstract void lol();
}
```

Comment: You implement interfaces, and extend classes.  You'll also note that the OP has already created a subclass of `NoiseMaker`.

Comment: Test-class implements an interface. I have updated it now. But that is not the problem I think. I want to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I see an issue with your `Test` class.  You implement `setNoisemaker`, but you don't store a reference to that `NoiseMaker` (e.g. have `private NoiseMaker myNoiseMaker;` in `Test`).  So you can't access the `NoiseMaker` (in this case a `Scream`) later to call `makeNoise()` on it.

I would add the myNoiseMaker field as shown above and then in `setNoiseMaker()` you can say `this.myNoiseMaker = nm;`.  Then you can call `myNoiseMaker.makeNoise();` in `doSomething()`.

Finally - to append the "ROAR" to your statement, you need to add `+ getNoiseName()` in the `makeNoise()` method of `Scream`

***EDIT***

Re-reading, I think you might want to append the "ROAR" in the `doSomething()` method.  In which case - I'd go for this (all other code remaining same):

```
public class Test implements MakeNoiser {
    public Test() {}

    private NoiseMaker myNoiseMaker;

    public void setNoiseMaker(NoiceMaker nm) {
       nm.makeNoise();
       myNoiseMaker = nm;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        //What to write in this method?
        myNoiseMaker.makeNoise();
        System.out.println(myNoiseMaker.getNoiseName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setNoiseMaker(new Scream("ROAR"));
        t.doSomething();
    }    
}
```

Comment: NoiseMaker is an abstract class so I can´t write
private NoiseMaker myNoiseMaker;

Comment: why do you think that? I have tested my solution - it works.  You can't *instantiate* an abstract class, but you can have a private (or public) member field with that class

Comment: I've just run it exactly as written, with your NoiseMaker and Scream classes. The output is `Scream out load: ` from the `setNoiseMaker` method and then `Scream out load: 
ROAR` from `doSomething()`.  Not really sure why this merits a -1

Comment: Sorry, you are right about the instansitate.
But I'm not allowed to make a member field with the class NoiseMaker. I'm somehow supposed to use the Scream-class. I have an UML I need to follow, and just fill in the blanks

Comment: Maybe post the UML? Otherwise we're flying blind.  My answer works, but seems to have attracted a negative vote but it hits everything you ask for in the question.  Or at least mark which bits of code you *are* allowed to change and which you *aren't* (e.g. I'm allowed to change `main` but not allowed to add member fields in `Test`)

Answer (score 0):

Just inherit from the abstract class and override the abstract method. You cannot call abstract method, they must be overridden.

`public class Test extend NoiseMaker {
    public void makeNoice() {
        System.out.println('hallo');
    }
}`

The `@Override` annotation is not needed. It will work without it.

Comment: Sorry, I´m not allowed to inherit from the abstract class (I have an UML I need to follow). Test-class implements an interface.

Comment: Abstract classes are designed to force the inherit from it. This is there only use of abstract. Maybe you are doing something wrong.